# No result when using Multiple write file & sed in shell script

Tags: sed, cat

I would like to swap variables from old file to new file
when I use single line like this

```
cat ../oldFile.html | sed "s@$dayMaxInNew@$dayMaxIn@g" > newFile
```

There's result from newFile.

But When I use more than 2 line as follows:

```
cat ../oldFile.html | sed "s@$dayMaxInNew@$dayMaxIn@g" > newFile

cat newFile | sed "s@$dayAvgInNew@$dayAvgIn@g" > newFile

cat newFile | sed "s@$dayCurInNew@$dayCurIn@g" >  newFile
```

no result from newFile. I try to use sleep but It doesn't Work.
PS. The 2nd and 3rd line I swap variable in samefile.
any advice?

Answer (score 3):

The redirection clobbers (clears) the file before the command runs. The command `sponge` from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/), soaks up its standard input before writing to a file. That way, the file is overwritten after the command has run.

```
cat ../oldFile.html | sed "s@$dayMaxInNew@$dayMaxIn@g" > newFile
cat newFile | sed "s@$dayAvgInNew@$dayAvgIn@g" | sponge newFile
cat newFile | sed "s@$dayCurInNew@$dayCurIn@g" | sponge  newFile
```

If you don't have moreutils, you can use temporary files. Also note that you don't have to use `cat`.

```
sed "s@$dayMaxInNew@$dayMaxIn@g" < ../oldFile.html > newFile
sed "s@$dayAvgInNew@$dayAvgIn@g" < newFile | sponge newFile
sed "s@$dayCurInNew@$dayCurIn@g" < newFile | sponge  newFile
```

And finally, you can combine multiple sed commands into one.

```
sed "s@$dayMaxInNew@$dayMaxIn@g
     s@$dayAvgInNew@$dayAvgIn@g
     s@$dayCurInNew@$dayCurIn@g" < ../oldFile.html > newFile
```

or

```
sed -e "s@$dayMaxInNew@$dayMaxIn@g" \
    -e "s@$dayAvgInNew@$dayAvgIn@g" \
    -e "s@$dayCurInNew@$dayCurIn@g" < ../oldFile.html > newFile
```

Comment: for Sponge,It swap only 1st variable but i used multiple command.It's work. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Never consume data from a file you're redirecting into; the redirection will clobber the file, usually before you've had a chance to read it. Use multiple `sed` commands instead.

```
sed "command1;command2;command3" < ../oldfile.html > newFile
```